# Translation to Japanese: "The test will determine which university I will go to."

Tags: translation, expressions

How do you say

> "The test will determine which university I will go to."

in Japanese? I only can figure out the first part of it, which is 「あのテストは…」

Can anyone here help me complete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A word-by-word translation would be:

> その試験が、私がどの大学に行くかを決める。

An active voice sentence with an abstract or lifeless noun as a subject (主語) sounds unnatural.
A better translation is:

> 試験の結果によってどの大学に行くかが決まる。

If you want to clarify “I”:

> 試験の結果によって私が行く大学が決まる。

Comment: I would use 入る instead of 行く.  The latter sounds like you're just going to the university to see the campus or something.  入る is more used for "entering" or being admitted to a school.

Comment: @istrasci Thanks. “行く” is ambiguous. It usually means visiting as you said. When used with schools, it may mean “通う”.

Comment: I think 行く and 入る both make perfect sense in this context. This 行く would be understood as going to college as a student, not as a mere visitor.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "A sentence with an abstract noun as a subject sounds unnatural."? Your two examples use その試験 and どの大学に行くか as the two subjects and you claim that the first one is abstract and sounds unnatural. I agree that the first sentence sounds more unnatural, but I don't understand the reasoning.

Comment: @無色受想行識 I mean a grammatical subject (主語).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with formal terminology. From what I understand, が is supposed to mark a "grammatical subject" and in the two sentences there is その試験が and どの大学に行くかが. Are you saying one of these is a grammatical subject and the other isn't?

Comment: @無色受想行識 Oops! Both are “grammatical subjects”. What I wanted to say was “grammatical subjects” should not be used in active voice. I’ll correct my answer. Thanks.